# how can useRef be used for storing previous state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
function Counter() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const prevCountRef = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    prevCountRef.current = count;  });
  const prevCount = prevCountRef.current;
  return <h1>Now: {count}, before: {prevCount}</h1>;
}
```

In the above snippet from the `React Hoks FAQS` `useRef` is used for saving the count. However whenever render is called, will not the `prevCount` be set to the current `count` as the `useEffect` will be called on each render, so how are count and prevCount different ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the `useEffect` callback function will be called after the `rendering time` of `Counter` Component has finished. and that's why `prevCount` is always one `tick` behind.

one point to consider is the change in in a `React ref` won't cause a rerender in React Component only `change in state and props` will cause a rerender.

see the working example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-butterfly-y66tc?file=/src/App.js

```
export default function Counter() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const prevCountRef = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    prevCountRef.current = count;
    console.log('me socond')
  });
  console.log('me first')
  const prevCount = prevCountRef.current;
  return (
    <h1>
      Now: {count}, before: {prevCount}
      <div onClick={() => setCount((v) => v + 1)}>click me</div>
    </h1>
  );
}
```

you see `me first` then `me second` in the console